# Disable context menus in ShellView control (GongShell Solution)

Tags: .net, winforms, window

In my Window Form application (.net 3.5).

I use ShellView control (http://gong-shell.sourceforge.net/) to browse a folder. It work perfect.

But i don't want display context menu when right-click on this control. How can i disable it?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Quick question. Is this control still of value? It seems pretty old and has that XP look. Would you not gain from using the built-in OpenFileDialog? Is it because you don't want a dialog?

Comment: I've never used it, but...is there a `ContextMenu` or `ContextMenuStrip` property on the control you're using? If so, you could try the quick and dirty hack of setting it to a new (empty) ContextMenu or ContextMenuStrip.

Comment: This is quite difficult, the control is a wrapper around the native Windows IShellBrowser interface.  You'd have to sub-class the native SysListView32 window to catch the WM_RBUTTONDOWN message.  Hard to do, especially since it recreates the browser frequently on the fly.  The Windows API Code Pack has an implementation of this as well.

Comment: To steinar: I don't want a dialog. I need a file list as a part of my form, so i use this control.

Comment: To Hans Passant: thanks for your comment. Can you show me some sample code to do that?